# Recursive request ? search and update node at the same time

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to do a request to update nodes but I have a little trouble.

My datas are like this :

(node1 {prop:1})<-(node2 {prop:null})<-(node3 {prop:null})

I want to update node2 {prop:2} and node3 {prop:3} depending on the node1 {prop1} value (+1)

My request is :

```
MATCH (n) <-[r]- (m) WHERE n.prop IS NOT NULL AND m.prop IS NULL SET m.prop = n.prop + 1;
```

But this only update node2, I need to execute the request again to update node3.

Is there a way to do this for every node ? I don't know how many node I will update (at this time I need to do the request 10 times, but maybe in the future it will be 15 times depending on the datas)

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
//get the first node
MATCH (head{prop:1})
// match all the following
MATCH p=(head)<-[r*1..]-(node)
// set the sequence 
SET node.prop = length(p) + 1
```